# MappingNotFoundException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/) tutorial.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

When I run App.Java, I get:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml not found
```

However, I have that file there as you can see it. When I put the file under

```
src/main/java/com/mykong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml
```

I am still getting this error.

How can I make this example work?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
hibernate.cfg.xml

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleapplication</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">MYPASSWORDHERE</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Could we see your hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: Spelling error: In your `hiberate.cfg.xml` file you have specified that the hibernate mapping file resides in the location: `com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml` However, in the package directory structure it is: `com/mykong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml`. Note the mykong; not mkyong.

Therefore, in the hibernate.cfg.xml file, please try changing

```
<mapping resource="com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

to the following:

```
<mapping resource="com/mykong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```