# org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml not found

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

No, this isn't the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7127608/1864054) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185683/hibernate-mapping-not-found-exception) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16267299/1864054).

for the simple reason that my *.hbm.xml files are already in the right directory (`src/main/resources/com/corp/dept/proj`).

Furthermore, it used to run fine, as long as I statically (i.e. hardcoded at build time) took everything from `hibernate.cfg.xml`, using this simple static method in my HibernateUtil.java:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

But since I wanted to move some of the parameters from `hibernate.cfg.xml` to a properties file to be read at runtime (e.g. DB's  *"connection.url"*):

```
static {
  try {
    sessionFactory = buildHibernateConfig().buildSessionFactory();
  } catch (Throwable ex) {
    System.out.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + ex.getMessage());
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }
}
```

and

```
private static Configuration buildHibernateConfig() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

  Properties properties = new Properties();
  sConfig = new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");

  try {
    properties.load(ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(MYWS_PROPS));
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.severe("Cannot find properties file " + MYWS_PROPS);
    throw new SecurityException("Server Error: couldn't open " + MYWS_PROPS + " file");
  }

  /*hardcoded*/sConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");/*hardcoded*/
  /*hardcoded*/sConfig.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");/*hardcoded*/
  sConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", properties.getProperty("dburl"));

  // Add Hibernate XML mappings
  sConfig.addClass(FooTbl.class);

  return sConfig;
}
```

I am getting a **runtime** exception:

```
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: resources/com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml

Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addClass
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml
Apr 03, 2014 14:31:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed: resource: com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml not found

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml not found
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:712)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addClass(Configuration.java:757)
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil.buildHibernateConfig(HibernateUtil.java:141)
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:56)
```

Now... prior to the exception, the log shows that the files ***are*** found. I also verified that the files are physically included in the WAR file in the same exact subdirectory they are expected. So, **why** is this error?

What is the recommended way to fix this?

Comment: try one test and copy the FooTbl.hbm.xml to the class folder, the same that you have your .class file located

Comment: I noticed that in your log file, when it finds the file, it is reading `resources/com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml` and when it doesn't it is trying to read `com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct solution:

Instead of going the *static initialization block* route, just stick with the original *static buildSessionFactory() method* and inject `Configuration.setProperty()` statements (as needed) in between the `Configuration.configure()` and the `Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()`. That is, instead of the original implementation of buildSessionFactory() that was posted in the question, I do:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  try {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config = config.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", properties.getProperty("dburl"));            
    SessionFactory session = config.buildSessionFactory();
    return session;
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }
}
```

No need for extending the `Configuration` class and... Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

After obtaining a Configuration (sConfig) instance you are trying to add XML mapping documents incorrectly. As you are using XML-based mapping files (.hbm),so to **add xml mapping files you need to use addResource() method, not the addClass() method**.

***addClass() method used to add the annotation based mappings.***

So replace

```
sConfig.addClass(FooTbl.class);
```

with

```
sConfig.addResource("com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml");
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I tried what you suggested and the problem is the same. I also tried it with `"resources/com/corp/dept/proj/FooTbl.hbm.xml"` and it resulted in a different problem. It looks like I will have to abandon the static initialization block approach, instead retaining the original implementation and just extending the `Configuration` class to override what's being read from the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If that works, I will post this as an answer. +1 for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your file FooTbl.hbm.xml name should match with class name in case of addClass() method.

Here your class name is FooTbl then mapping file name should be FooTbl.hbm.xml otherwise exception will generate.

try this. :)